# fetching data from mysql using unhex

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have an sql request, I want to search data using unhex function.
in my table, a column called text but to fetch the real data I use `unhex(text)`.

```
select unhex(text) from my_table.
```

this request return for me all rows without any problems

but I want to search row based keyword.

my request is:

```
select unhex(text) from my_table where UNHEX(text) LIKE '% keyword %')
```

I tried to use it using mysql but does not work, and with symfony too, this is not working

any help PLZ

Comment: You have extra and missing chars in your query, it should be: `select unhex(text) from my_table where UNHEX(text) LIKE 'keyword'` (swap the last bracket for a single quote). Also, text is a keyword, so escape it with backticks (`)

Comment: cant you just search for  `hex(keyword)` ?

Comment: What is error message?

Comment: Why are you storing text as hex in the first place?